# Ogre Render Lines completely wrong

Tags: c++, ogre

I'm trying to render line list using indices of triangles as follow

```
float *vertices = static_cast<float *>(vertexBuffer->lock(Ogre::HardwareBuffer::HBL_DISCARD));

for (int i = 0; i < out.numberofpoints; i++)
{
    vertices[(i*3)] = out.pointlist[(i*3)];
    vertices[(i*3)+1] = out.pointlist[(3*i)+1];
    vertices[(i*3) + 2] = out.pointlist[(3*i)+2];

}

vertexBuffer->unlock();

uint16_t *indices = static_cast<uint16_t *>(indexBuffer->lock(Ogre::HardwareBuffer::HBL_DISCARD));


int  l, t;
int numTriangles = out.numberoftrifaces*3*sizeof(uint16_t);
for (l = 0, t = 0; t<numTriangles; t += 3) {
    // Each vertex has to be listed twice
    indices[l] = out.trifacelist[t];      l++;
    indices[l] = out.trifacelist[t + 1];    l++;
    indices[l] = out.trifacelist[t + 2];    l++;
    indices[l] = out.trifacelist[t + 2];    l++;
    indices[l] = out.trifacelist[t + 1];    l++;
    indices[l] = out.trifacelist[t];      l++;
}


indexBuffer->unlock();
```

The problem that ogre renders broken triangles and it's completely wrong. I'm not doing anything wrong regarding rendering the lines that the triangles are composed

I'm using ogre 1.9

[image]

Comment: Can you post an image?

Comment: @Bálint I posted an image.

Answer (score 1):

The triangles you're drawing per iteration of the loop are the triangles:

```
t, t + 1, t + 1
```

And

```
t + 2, t + 2, t
```

These are degenerate triangles, presumably you want:

```
t, t + 1, t + 2
t + 2, t + 1, t
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. and how much would be the size of line index ?

Comment: This should draw triangles or line list ?

Comment: I attached the picture, still broken triangles